# Launch chrome extension from page button, instead of extension icon

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing chrome extension, it works fine when click extension icon in browser.[image]

but I want to run the extension, from button click on the page. I can add a button to the page, but how should I run the extension when click the button.
[image]

Comment: Depends on what you mean by `run extension`. But anyway, the only way to add a button on the page is a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Comment: 'run extension' mean running a popup

Comment: Not possible. The toolbar popup is only shown on toolbar icon click or a hotkey declared via chrome.commands API. You can display your UI as a normal DOM element in the page though.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance !